# TypeError with quiver plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a quiver plot in Jupyter Notebook but I'm getting a TypeError the way I'm defining my u,v arrays. I have an array `ug` with the velocity norm (it only has x-component) so I'm doing:

```
ug = [0.0 0.072 0.128 0.16800000000000004 0.19200000000000006 0.20000000000000007 0.19200000000000006 0.16800000000000004 0.128 0.07200000000000001 1.734723475976807e-17]                    
xg = np.linspace(0,l,int(l/50))
yg = np.linspace(0,d,len(ug))

(Xg,Yg) = np.meshgrid(xg,yg)
(Vg,Ug) = np.meshgrid(0*xg,ug)

plt.quiver(Xg,Yg,Ug,Vg)
```

The last line, the call to `quiver`, raises the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Why does `quiver` reject these arrays?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. [This is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q764L.png), which seems fine.

Comment: I've added my `ug` vector which seems to be the problem here...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ug` must be a list, instead of a np.array. I've changed:

```
ug = list(ud[::4])
```

and it works!